# Starting bootcamp - MacTerminal and Github SSH fingerprint don't match

Tags: macos, github, terminal, ssh-keys

I have been following the steps of the courses pre-work, including:

- checking for, generating, copy/paste, and
- saving the SSH keys to GitHub.

But when I am instructed to check the matching fingerprints using "`ssh -T git@github.com`", the prints don't match.

I've even started from the beginning clear through, but they still don't match.
Thought I'd reach out here before using my 1 tutoring.
Hopefully the screenshot showing what I see helps(link).

[image: error]

EDIT- I understand there's some stuff in there that shouldn't be, I was just trying things for diff results. I would just like to know where I went wrong and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

What you ssh is the remote site SSH key fingerprint, *not* you registered SSH key fingerprint.

You see (or should see if you are contacting the correct `github.com`) the fingerprints exposed with [`api.github.com/meta`](https://api.github.com/meta) as [explained here](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-18-githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/).

Using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), you can [add them to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`](https://serverfault.com/a/1098531/783) with:

```bash
curl --silent https://api.github.com/meta \
  | jq --raw-output '"github.com "+.ssh_keys[]' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

From there, you can [test your connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) with `ssh -Tv github.com`, and check if you see a welcome message:

```
Hi username! 
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
```